An error occurred while reading data from the provider: The remote certificate is not valid according to the validation procedure, PowerBI Postgresql
I wanted to use PowerBI to view and manage things on my Postgresql Database server, but when I select obtain data from another source and select Postgresql DB and enter the credentials (server, DB name, username and password), the error message pops up.
error:

An error occurred while reading data from the provider: 'The remote certificate is not valid according to the validation procedure.'"

Any idea how I can solve it? (I have the certificate installed on the PC and the ssl from the DB is correctly configured)
